# Algolia Group Results

Tags: algolia

**I have the following scenario of records**

*ProyectA* APARTMENT 1 specs of the apartment

*ProyectA* APARTMENT 2 specs of the apartment

*ProyectB* APARTMENT 1 specs of the apartment

*ProyectB* APARTMENT 2 specs of the apartment

**I will like to only show as result a group of the proyect, example:**

Results 2:

ProyectA

ProyectB

*If you have another approach to this scenario that we can structure our data please let us know, keep in mind that every apartment has different specifications like pricing , measurements etc...

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is using the [distinct](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/ranking/distinct/) and [attributeForDistinct](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/attributeForDistinct/) features to group results based on one of their common attributes.

Let's imagine the following records:

```
[
  {
    "project": "Alpha",
    "apartment": "Skylines"
  },
  {
    "project": "Alpha",
    "apartment": "Cozy"
  },
  {
    "project": "Beta",
    "apartment": "Skyfall"
  },
  {
    "project": "AAA",
    "apartment": "Cortana"
  }
]
```

If you define in your index `distinct: true` and `attributesForDistinct: project`, then your results will only ever contain one of project Alpha and one of Project Beta.

Which one will it be will depend on your other relevance settings. The most relevant result for each project (according to you current search) will always be returned. So for example if you're searching for "Sky", you will have the Skylines from Alpha and the Skyfall from Beta.

If you're not searching for any keyword, then they will be ordered by what you defined in your `customRanking` (it can be by price, by popularity, etc).